# Chemfig: aligning multiple equations

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I am trying to visualize the reaction to obtain fat. I want to align each of fatty acids on top of each other, without a connection. How can I stack them without a connection? I have tried using \phantom{-} on the bond, unsuccessfully. I have also been having problems with the length of some of the bonds. Any help is appreciated.

The following code is in a scheme envirenment.

```
\chemname{\chemfig[atom sep=2em]{H-C((-[6]C(-[4]H)(-[6]H)(-\charge{90=\|,-90=\|}{O}-H))(-\charge{90=\|,-90=\|}{O}-H))(-[2]C(-[4]H)(-[2]H)(-\charge{90=\|,-90=\|}{O}-H))}}{Glycerin}
\+
\chemname{\chemfig[atom sep=2em, vshift=2em]{({R_2}(--{COOH})(-[6]{R_3}(--{COOH}))(-[2]{R_1}(--{COOH})))}}{fatty acids}
```

Image of the pdf produced

[image]

Comment: Please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust general parameters for all molecules before starting the document.

Start drawing glycerin by central carbon and fatty acid by R2

......................................................

```
\setchemfig{atom sep=2.5em,  cram width = 2pt, cram dash width = 0.2pt, cram dash sep = 0.4pt, bond offset = 1pt}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemname{\chemfig{C(-[4]H)(-[0]\charge{90=\|,270=\|}{O}-H)(-[2]C(-[4]H)(-[2]H)(-[0]\charge{90=\|,270=\|}{O}-H))(-[6]C(-[4]H)(-[6]H)(-[0]\charge{90=\|,270=\|}{O}-H))}}{Glycerin}
%
\+
%
\chemname{\chemfig{\charge{330:2pt=$\scriptstyle2$}{R}(-[0]COOH)(-[2]\charge{330:2pt=$\scriptstyle1$}{R}-[0]COOH)(-[6]\charge{330:2pt=$\scriptstyle3$}{R}-[0]COOH)}}{Fatty acids}
\schemestop
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setchemfig{atom sep=2em}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemname{\chemfig{C(-[4]H)(-[0]\charge{90=\|,270=\|}{O}-H)(-[2]C(-[4]H)(-[2]H)(-[0]\charge{90=\|,270=\|}{O}-H))(-[6]C(-[4]H)(-[6]H)(-[0]\charge{90=\|,270=\|}{O}-H))}}{Glycerin}
\+
\chemname{\chemfig{R|_2|\vphantom{C}(-[2]R|_1|\vphantom{C}-[,0.8]COOH)(-[6]R|_3|\vphantom{C}-[,0.8]COOH)-[,0.8]COOH}}{Fatty acids}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]